# Ruby start_with? Serial Data

Tags: ruby, string, serial-port

I am reading a serial port successfully using Ruby. Serial data is from Arduino with GSM shield so I am getting a lot of extra strings from the GSM shield. In order to filter the SMS messages I want I have attempted to use the start_with? method. I have tested this in IRB and it is returning true or false correctly.

```
rb(main):006:0> 'Timedgf'.start_with? 'Time'
=> true
irb(main):007:0> 'AT'.start_with? 'Time'
=> false
```

When I don't use start_with? all the serial data comes through including SMS. When I use start_with? as in the below code, I get nothing even when I SMS something beginning with Time.
My code as follows:

```
require "rubygems" 
require "serialport" 
require "data_mapper"

#params for serial port 
port_str = "/dev/ttyACM0"
baud_rate = 19200 
data_bits = 8 
stop_bits = 1 
parity = SerialPort::NONE 

sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity) 

loop do
 sp_char = sp.getc
   if sp_char.start_with? 'Time'
   printf("%c", sp_char)
 end
end
```

Ruby version 1.9.3p194

Comment: Don't you get individual characters instead of full lines? That can be the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check what Priti said.

Then:

Your rs232 device most probably emits the data in lines. Try reading by `sp.gets` instead, and maybe your code will instantly work.

OTOH, if your device does not (or if it overflows the buffers etc) and the gets starts returning partial data, then you'll have to iteratively getc/or/gets and accumulate that data in some your own buffer, and then analyze the buffer's contents instead of just looking at what most recently came over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [`getc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-getc) :

> Reads a one-character string from ios. Returns nil if called at end of file.

That's why :

```
'T'.start_with? 'Time' # => false
'Time'.start_with? 'T' # => true
```

[`String#start_with`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) says :

> Returns true if str starts *with one of the prefixes* given.

```
'Time'.start_with?('L','Ti') # => true
'AT'.start_with?('Time','A') # => true
```

Comment: user2549208: Your rs232 device most probably emits the data in lines. Try reading by `sp.gets` instead, and maybe your code will instantly work. OTOH, if your device does not (or if it overflows the buffers etc) and the gets starts returning partial data, then you'll have to iteratively getc/or/gets and accumulate that data in some your own buffer, and then analyze the buffer's contents instead of just looking at what most recently came over the wire.

Comment: Thanks Priti, iltempo and quetzalcoatl. Changed to sp.gets and printf argument to %s. Works as it should now. Portmapper next!